# How can I change path to new partion on second SSD?

Tags: linux, path, partition

I created partition on my second SSD. To acces it I need to write very long path.

```
/media/ivan/8845bdd5-64ba-45be-90f6-83fd38ca946b
```

How can I change this path to something shorter?

Comment: Please use [su] or [unix.se] for this kind of questions. This site here is for programming questions only and general OS and hardware support is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic link where you want using **linux command** `ln`.

For more details read this [guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/)